# Can I build only React CRA product build webpack craco?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, esbuild, craco

I'm developing REACT CRA and building client and ssr build using craco and distributing production.
However, the local development server is slow to start and the change after saving the changes is very slow. So I successfully started the local server using only vite.

My concern is that if I use the local development server with vite and the production deployment with craco, I'm worried about whether there will be a conflict or a gap between the two environments.

Is it okay to continue in this environment?